# How to Pre fill wise installer Dialog

Tags: installation, silent-installer, wise

I am trying to support this legacy application where we use wise installer to create our application installer. I can see that script will take parameters.

What I want is that when user run installer, the install dialog should have values pre-filled. For this I did some research and found that I can put those parameters in a file and then call installer with a tag and parameters file name.

Here is syntax that I tired

```
MyAppSetup.exe /M="C:\USERS\User1\DOCUMENTS\MyAppSetup.txt"
```

where MyAppSetup.txt has parameter names and it values. MyAppSetup.txt contents is as below

```
COMPANY="ABC"  
SERIALNUMBER="123" 
...   
...
```

Now installer runs correctly, but values are not prefilled.

But if I run the installer in silent mode, it dose uses the parameters correctly.

Here is syntax to run the same script in silent mode.

```
MyAppSetup.exe /S /M="C:\USERS\User1\DOCUMENTS\MyAppSetup.txt"
```

I would really appreciate if someone can guide me on how to call installer visually and have values prefilled.

Here are some useful links that I found

[What are the command line parameters available for WiseScript?](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO5865.html)

[Wise Setup.exe Switches](http://www.itninja.com/blog/view/wise-setup-exe-switches)

Answer (score 0):

Use a .ini file, then the installer will read those values and populate the dialog quite nicely. Here's an example of a C:\MyApp\MyAppSettings.ini:

```
[settings]
COMPANY=ABC
SERIALNUMBER=123
```

...and a .wse that will populate a dialog:

```
item: Set Variable
  Variable=MAINDIR
  Value=C:\MyApp
end
item: Set Variable
  Variable=COMPANY
end
item: Set Variable
  Variable=SERIAL
end
item: Read INI Value
  Variable=COMPANY
  Pathname=%MAINDIR%\MyAppSettings.ini
  Section=settings
  Item=COMPANY
end
item: Read INI Value
  Variable=SERIAL
  Pathname=%MAINDIR%\MyAppSettings.ini
  Section=settings
  Item=SERIALNUMBER
end
item: Custom Dialog Set
  Name=My App Settings
  item: Dialog
    Title=My App Settings
    Width=290
    Height=238
    Font Name=Helv
    Font Size=8
    item: Static
      Rectangle=5 5 105 20
      Enabled Color=00000000000000001111111111111111
      Create Flags=01010000000000000000000000000000
      Text=Company Name
    end
    item: Editbox
      Rectangle=114 7 230 22
      Help Context=16711681
      Enabled Color=00000000000000001111111111111111
      Create Flags=01010000100000010000000000000000
      Text=%COMPANY%
    end
    item: Static
      Rectangle=5 25 105 40
      Enabled Color=00000000000000001111111111111111
      Create Flags=01010000000000000000000000000000
      Text=Serial Number
    end
    item: Editbox
      Rectangle=114 26 230 41
      Help Context=16711681
      Enabled Color=00000000000000001111111111111111
      Create Flags=01010000100000010000000000000000
      Text=%SERIAL%
    end
    item: Push Button
      Rectangle=182 145 217 160
      Enabled Color=00000000000000001111111111111111
      Create Flags=01010000000000010000000000000000
      Text=&Next
    end
  end
end
```